# Errror when trying to find index of list variables: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

The following is my code where I get the value error stated above.

```
citiesR = [melbourneR, perthR, brisbaneR]
print(citiesR.index(melbourneR))
print(citiesR.index(perthR))



 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-43-517b86a5b2b0> in <module>
      1 citiesR = [melbourneR, perthR, brisbaneR]
      2 print(citiesR.index(melbourneR))
----> 3 print(citiesR.index(perthR))

      ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() 
      or a.all()
```

Printing melbourneR, the first element of the list gives me the index value correctly but trying to print PerthR gives me this error and I can't work out why.
The variables in the list are all numpy arrays with the same shape (365,).

Comment: The error s raised when a boolean array is used in a context that expects a scalar boolean.  An `if` expression is a comon one; here it must be tbe list index.

Comment: @hpaulj List index? How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Printing melbourneR, the first element of the list gives me the index value correctly

That's because it is identified by object identity.

> but trying to print PerthR gives me this error and I can't work out why.

Because it's a different object than the list's first object, an *equality*-check is done. Which results in an array of booleans. Which, as the error message says, has an ambiguous (or rather no) truth value. So when the `index` function goes like "Is this it? If so then return 0", the question "Is this it?" doesn't get answered and you get that error instead.

In other words, your

```
citiesR.index(perthR)
```

is pretty much equivalent to this:

```
next(i
     for i, city in enumerate(citiesR)
     if city is perthR or city == perthR)
```

This should work (untested, as there's no test data):

```
next(i
     for i, city in enumerate(citiesR)
     if (city == perthR).all())
```

Comment: Thanks for that, so is there any way of getting around this as I want to make this into a loop eventually with a large list of cities?

Comment: Maybe there's something short if you use a numpy array instead of a list. Alternatively, `print(next(i for i, city in enumerate(citiesR) if (city == perthR).all()))` should work (untested, as you didn't provide test data). Note the `all()`, that's missing when you use the `index` method.

Comment: @LukeHickinbotham Added more to the answer.

Comment: thanks for that, that works for perthR. So if I were to loop through all the cities in the list, which part of that would I need to change. Sorry, I've never seen that type of loop before.

Comment: If you "loop through all the cities in the list", you probably shouldn't be doing the searching at all. Instead just use `enumerate` in the first place.